# Не получается сделать слайдер в JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

JS

```
'use strict'
let slidCounter = 0;
let slid1= document.getElementById('slid1');
let slid2= document.getElementById('slid2');
let div = document.getElementById('fir1');
let div1 = document.getElementById('fir2');
let div2 = document.getElementById('fir3');
let div3 = document.getElementById('fir4');
let div4 = document.getElementById('fir5');
slid1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    slidCounter = slidCounter+1;
    if (slidCounter == 6){
        slidCounter = 1;
    }
    switch (slidCounter){      
      case 1:  
      div.style.display = "none";
      div1.style.display = "contents";
      console.log("1");
      break;
      case 2:  
      div1.style.display = "none";
      div2.style.display = "contents";
                  console.log("2");
      break;
      case 3:  
      div2.style.display = "none";
      div3.style.display = "contents";
                  console.log("3");
      break;
      case 4:  
      div3.style.display = "none";
      div4.style.display = "contents";
                  console.log("4");
      break;
      case 5: 
      div4.style.display = "none";
      div.style.display = "contents";
                  console.log("5");
      break;
      console.log("1");
}
});
```

CSS (не особо нужен)

```
.kit_slides_wrapper{
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    width: 800px;
}
.kit_slide{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
    width: 800px;
}
.kit_slide img{
  width: 250px;
}
.kit_slide .info{
  width: 510px;
}


.slider_arrow_left{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 220px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider_arrow_right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 220px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

html

```
   <!--Стреки для листания слайдера-->
      <img src="img/arrow_right.png" class="slider_arrow_right" id="slid1">
      <img src="img/arrow_left.png" class="slider_arrow_left" id="slid2">
  
  <!-- НАЧАЛО Слайд №1-->
    <div class="kit_slide" id="fir1">
      <img src="img/series/series1.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>THE LEGO MOVIE</h3>
        <p>
        а
        </p>
      </div>
        
    <div class="kit_slide" style="display:none" id="fir2">
      <img src="img/series/series2.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>STAR WARS</h3>
        <p>
        а 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="kit_slide" style="display:none"id="fir3">
      <img src="img/series/series3.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>NINJAGO</h3>
        <p>
        а
        </p>
      </div>
        
    <div class="kit_slide" style="display:none" id="fir4">
      <img src="img/series/series4.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>CITY</h3>
        <p>
         а
          </p>
      </div>
      <div class="kit_slide" style="display:none" id="fir5">
      <img src="img/series/series5.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>TECHNIC</h3>
        <p>
          а
        </p>
      </div>
```

Извиняюсь за жутко массивный код, я не знаю как сделать по другому.
Когда нажимаю на правую стрелку пропадает div, но div1 не появляется. Почему??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном примере невалидная вёрстка - не хватает закрывающих тэгов div. Если вот так, то ваш код для листания вправо работает. Кроме этого добавила вариант, как упростить ваш js

```js
'use strict'
let slidCounter = 0;
let next= document.getElementById('slid1');
let prev= document.getElementById('slid2');
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.kit_slide');
let slidesCount = slides.length;

function parseSlides () {
    slides.forEach(function(slideNode, slideIndex) {
    if (slideIndex == slidCounter) {
        slideNode.style.display = 'contents';
    } else {
        slideNode.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

next.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    slidCounter++;
  if (slidCounter >= slidesCount){
    slidCounter = 0;
  }
  console.log(slidCounter);
  parseSlides();
});

prev.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  slidCounter--;
  if (slidCounter < 0){
    // нумерация слайдов с 0, поэтому -1
    slidCounter = slidesCount - 1;
  }
  console.log(slidCounter);
  parseSlides();
});
```

```css
.kit_slides_wrapper{
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    width: 800px;
}
.kit_slide{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
    width: 800px;
}
.kit_slide img{
  width: 250px;
}
.kit_slide .info{
  width: 510px;
}


.slider_arrow_left{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 220px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider_arrow_right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 220px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <!--Стреки для листания слайдера-->
    <img src="img/arrow_right.png" class="slider_arrow_right" id="slid1">
    <img src="img/arrow_left.png" class="slider_arrow_left" id="slid2">
    
    <!-- НАЧАЛО Слайд №1-->
    <div class="kit_slide" id="fir1">
      <img src="img/series/series1.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>THE LEGO MOVIE</h3>
        <p>а</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="kit_slide" style="display:none;" id="fir2">
      <img src="img/series/series2.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>STAR WARS</h3>
        <p>а</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="kit_slide" style="display:none;" id="fir3">
      <img src="img/series/series3.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>NINJAGO</h3>
        <p>а</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="kit_slide" style="display:none;" id="fir4">
      <img src="img/series/series4.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>CITY</h3>
        <p>а</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="kit_slide" style="display:none;" id="fir5">
      <img src="img/series/series5.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>TECHNIC</h3>
        <p>а</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
class Slider {
  #node = null;
  #allNodes = null;
  #activeItem = {
    sliderItemNode: null,
    sliderDotNode: null,
    i: null,
  };
    #cssFocusActive = false;

    get cssFocusActive() {
        return this.#cssFocusActive;
    }

    get allNodes() {
        this.#allNodes;
    }

  get activeItem() {
    return this.#activeItem;
  }

  get sliderItemActiveClass() {
    return 'slider__item_active';
  }
  get sliderDotActiveClass() {
    return 'slider__dot_active';
  }
  get node() {
    return this.#node; // это слайдер в дереве
  }
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {Object[]} images Массив изображений
   * @param {string} images[].url url картинки
   * @param {string} images[].alt alt картинки
   * @param {string} selector селектор, куда вставим slider
   */
  constructor(images, selector, activeIndex) {
    if (activeIndex > images.length - 1) {
      throw new Error(
        "activeIndex больше, чем возможный индекс элемента в массиве images"
      );
    }

    this.#node = document.querySelector(selector);

    this.#allNodes = this.#createSliderNode(images, activeIndex);
    this.#insertChildIntoParent(this.#allNodes.resultNode, this.#node);
        this.#addKeyboardEvent();
  }

  #createSliderNode(images, activeIndex) {
    const resultNode = document.createElement("div");
        resultNode.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
        resultNode.addEventListener('focusin', () => {this.#eventFocusInSlider()});
        resultNode.addEventListener('focusout', () => {this.#eventFocusOutSlider()});

    const sliderNavigationNode = this.#createNode("div", [
      "slider__navigation",
    ]);
    const sliderArrowsWrapperNode = this.#createNode("div", ["slider__arrows"]);
    const sliderArrowPrevNode = this.#createNode("div", [
      "slider__arrow",
      "slider__arrow_prev",
    ]);
    const sliderArrowNextNode = this.#createNode("div", [
      "slider__arrow",
      "slider__arrow_next",
    ]);

    sliderArrowPrevNode.innerText = "<";
    sliderArrowNextNode.innerText = ">";

    sliderArrowsWrapperNode.append(sliderArrowPrevNode, sliderArrowNextNode);
    sliderNavigationNode.append(sliderArrowsWrapperNode);

    const sliderDotsWrapperNode = this.#createNode("div", ["slider__dots"]);
    const sliderItemsWrapperNode = this.#createNode("div", ["slider__items"]);

    const sliderDotArrNodes = [];
    const sliderItemArrNodes = [];
    const sliderImageArrNodes = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      const sliderItemNode = this.#createNode("div", ["slider__item"]);
      const sliderDotNode = this.#createNode("div", ["slider__dot"]);
            sliderDotNode.addEventListener('click', () => this.#eventClickDot(i, sliderItemArrNodes, sliderDotArrNodes));
      const sliderImageNode = this.#createNode(
        "img",
        ["slider__image"],
        [
          { name: "src", value: images[i].url },
          { name: "alt", value: images[i].alt },
        ]
      );

      if (i === activeIndex) {
        sliderItemNode.classList.add(this.sliderItemActiveClass);
        sliderDotNode.classList.add(this.sliderDotActiveClass);
        this.#activeItem = {
          sliderItemNode,
          sliderDotNode,
          i,
        };
      }

      sliderItemArrNodes.push(sliderItemNode);
      sliderDotArrNodes.push(sliderDotNode);
      sliderImageArrNodes.push(sliderImageNode);

      sliderItemNode.append(sliderImageNode);
      sliderItemsWrapperNode.append(sliderItemNode);
      sliderDotsWrapperNode.append(sliderDotNode);
    }

    sliderNavigationNode.append(sliderDotsWrapperNode);
    resultNode.append(sliderItemsWrapperNode);
    resultNode.append(sliderNavigationNode);

    sliderArrowNextNode.addEventListener("click", (e) =>
      this.#eventClickArrow(1, sliderItemArrNodes, sliderDotArrNodes)
    );
    sliderArrowPrevNode.addEventListener("click", (e) =>
      this.#eventClickArrow(-1, sliderItemArrNodes, sliderDotArrNodes)
    );

    return {
      resultNode,
      sliderNavigationNode,
      sliderArrowsWrapperNode,
      sliderArrowPrevNode,
      sliderArrowNextNode,
      sliderDotArrNodes,
      sliderItemArrNodes,
      sliderDotsWrapperNode,
      sliderItemsWrapperNode,
      sliderImageArrNodes,
    };
  }

  #insertChildIntoParent(child, parent) {
    parent.append(child);
  }

  #createNode(nodeName, cssClassesArray = [], attributes = []) {
    const node = document.createElement(nodeName);
    node.classList.add(...cssClassesArray);
    for (const attribute of attributes) {
      node.setAttribute(attribute.name, attribute.value);
    }
    return node;
  }

    #nextSlide(nextIndex, lastIndex, sliderItems, sliderDots) {
        sliderItems[lastIndex].classList.remove(this.sliderItemActiveClass);
    sliderDots[lastIndex].classList.remove(this.sliderDotActiveClass);

        const nextSliderItem = sliderItems[nextIndex];
    const nextSliderDot = sliderDots[nextIndex];

        nextSliderItem.classList.add(this.sliderItemActiveClass);
    nextSliderDot.classList.add(this.sliderDotActiveClass);

    this.#activeItem = {
      sliderItemNode: nextSliderItem,
      sliderDotNode: nextSliderDot,
      i: nextIndex,
    };
    }

    #dirChangeSlider(dir, sliderItems, sliderDots) {
        const lastIndex = this.#activeItem.i;
    const nextIndex = (lastIndex + dir + sliderItems.length) % sliderItems.length;

    this.#nextSlide(nextIndex, lastIndex, sliderItems, sliderDots);
    }

  #eventClickArrow(dir, sliderItems, sliderDots) {
    this.#dirChangeSlider(dir, sliderItems, sliderDots);
  }

    #eventClickDot(nextIndex, sliderItems, sliderDots) {
        const lastIndex = this.#activeItem.i;

        this.#nextSlide(nextIndex, lastIndex, sliderItems, sliderDots);
    }

    #eventFocusInSlider(event) {
        this.#cssFocusActive = true;
    }

    #eventFocusOutSlider(event) {
        this.#cssFocusActive = false;
    }

    #addKeyboardEvent() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {this.#eventKeyDown(e)});
    }

  /**
   * @param {KeyboardEvent} event
   */   
    #eventKeyDown(event) {
        const key = event.key;

        if (this.#cssFocusActive === false) {
            return false;
        }

        const sliderItems = this.#allNodes.sliderItemArrNodes;
        const sliderDots = this.#allNodes.sliderDotArrNodes;

        if (key === 'ArrowLeft') {
            this.#dirChangeSlider(-1, sliderItems, sliderDots);
        } else if (key === 'ArrowRight') {
            this.#dirChangeSlider(1, sliderItems, sliderDots);
        }
    }
}

const images = [
  { url: "https://picsum.photos/2000/1000", alt: "картинка-1" },
  { url: "https://picsum.photos/1900/1000", alt: "картинка-2" },
  { url: "https://picsum.photos/1800/1000", alt: "картинка-3" },
  { url: "https://picsum.photos/1700/1000", alt: "картинка-4" },
  { url: "https://picsum.photos/1600/1000", alt: "картинка-5" },
];

const slider1 = new Slider(images, ".slider", 0);
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
    user-select: none;
}

.slider__items {
  height: 100%;
}

.slider__item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.slider__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slider__item_active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider__arrows {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slider__arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
}

.slider__arrow:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.slider__arrow_next {
  right: 0;
}

.slider__dots {
    --sizeDot: 15px;
  position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    gap: calc(var(--sizeDot) / 1.5);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    background-color: red;
}

.slider__dot {
  width: var(--sizeDot);
  height: var(--sizeDot);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider__dot_active {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.slider__dot:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">

</div>
```